# Recovering MySQL items with specific ID

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a database where items are stored with a specefic ID (EventCode). When I try to display them on my website with their unique ID, it's all messed up. Some items are ok, and show A, B, C and D correctly. Some others items show the same A, B, C and D of others events. When I look at the EventCode for each item, it's a different code... so regarding to the code below, what is my problem? Why does some item show perfecly what they are supposed the show, and others show the same as items alredy created?

```
<?php
include('base.php');
?>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['EventCode']))
{
     $EventCode = intval($_GET['EventCode']);
     $dn = mysql_query("select A, B, C, D from users_event where EventCode=$EventCode ");
     if(mysql_num_rows($dn)>0)
     {
             $dnn = mysql_fetch_array($dn);
     ?>
 This is the profile of "<?php echo htmlentities($dnn['A']); ?>" :
 <table style="width:500px;">
     <tr>
     <td><?php
 if($dnn['B']!='')
{
     echo '<img src="'.htmlentities($dnn['B']).'" alt="B" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;" />';
}
else
{
     echo 'B is not existing.';
}
?>
</td>
     <td class="left"><h1><?php echo htmlentities($dnn['C']); ?></h1>
     Field: <?php echo htmlentities($dnn['D']); ?><br />
      </tr>
 </table>
<?php
     }
     else
     {
             echo 'Sorry, no record found.';
     }
}
else
{
     echo 'No item found';
}
?>
                      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stay away from mysql_* ._. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: http://yoursite.com?EventCode=1;CREATE%20TABLE%0sql_injection(yes%20INT);--

Comment: @sammit: won't work. the `(intval)` will force the value to be just an int. but yes, otherwise there'd be an injection vulnerability.

Comment: NOthing in this could would rearrange the values like that. Are you sure they're in the DB in the right order? e.g. try running the various queries manually and see what you get for different records.

Comment: Yes, they are all in the DB, in the right order!

Comment: I assume you only want 1 row returned

Comment: Yes! Only one row at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$EventCode` is not unique, you'll only get the 'first' record only, because you're not iterating over your resultset.

If you want to list all the records:
- Do a `while ($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($dn)) { /*...*/ }`

If you only want one record: - Use a UNIQUE key or combination. Alternatively you can ORDER and LIMIT your query.

Comment: The event code is unique. I actually have the list of all the records. The problem is when I click on a specific record, it sometimes show the same elements of an other record.